# How to avoid thread block in Qt when using delay function in multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

In the main thread I define the function as following :

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        qDebug() << "Main thread: " << m_th;

        QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(500);
        while (QTime::currentTime() < dieTime)
            QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 500);
    }
```

In the sub thread I define the function as following :

```
    for (size_t jj = 0; jj < 10; ++jj)
{
        qDebug() << "Sub thread: " <<pcloud->points.size();

        QTime dieTime = QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(500);
        while (QTime::currentTime() < dieTime)
            QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 500);

}
```

Start the two threads respectively , the output shows as following:

Sub thread: 25602

Sub thread: 51202

Sub thread: 76802

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Main thread: 0

Sub thread: 102402

Sub thread: 128002

I start the sub thread first and then start the main thread. Obviously, the main thread blocks the sub thread.
Can I avoid the thread block? How? Thanks !

Comment: I don't see what is obvious about that. How threads share a core is controlled by the OS. I don't really understand the "problem" or what solution you are looking for. My only idea to have fine grained control over the order of execution here is to use a single thread

Comment: ***Obviously, the main thread blocks the sub thread.*** I am not sure that this is shown. What are the events that are being processed in both threads?

Comment: In fact, I clicked a button to start the sub thread, and every 500ms it output "Sub thread: 102402". After 1500ms(3 program statements have been output), I clicked another button and it started the main thread, where "Main thread: 0" would been output every 500ms. As we can see, the sub thread was blocked because it stoped output "Sub thread: 102402". After the main thread over, the sub thread output again until the sub thread over.